# Docker use same image for all php projects

Tags: php, docker, redis, phpmyadmin

I want to use docker, but the problem I have is:
When I was using xampp, I only had one phpmyadmin and one redis for my php projects and all the projects used the same.
But now I have to have a separate phpmyadmin with Docker for each project with a separate port
Do you have a solution? All localhost projects use a phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single instance of phpMyAdmin with Docker for multiple projects without having to allocate separate ports for each project. Here's a general approach:

Docker Compose for Multiple Services:
Use Docker Compose to define a multi-container Docker application. This allows you to set up multiple services, including phpMyAdmin, and link them to your PHP projects.

Networks:
Create a Docker network to allow communication between the containers. This way, your PHP projects and phpMyAdmin can communicate within the same network, and you won't need separate ports for each project.

Environment Variables:
Leverage environment variables in your Docker Compose file to configure the connection details for phpMyAdmin, such as the database host, username, and password. This makes it easier to manage and update configurations across different projects.

Here's a simplified example of a Docker Compose file:

```
    version: '3'

services:
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
    ports:
      - "8080:80"  # You can access phpMyAdmin at http://localhost:8080

  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=mydatabase
      - MYSQL_USER=myuser
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypassword
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  php_project:
    build: ./path/to/your/php_project
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - mynetwork

networks:
  mynetwork:
```

In this example:

phpmyadmin is the phpMyAdmin service.
db is a MySQL database service.
php_project is your PHP project service.
They all share the same network (mynetwork), allowing communication.
Adjust the configurations and versions based on your specific needs and project setup. You can then access phpMyAdmin at http://localhost:8080 or the designated port you set in the ports section.

Remember to replace placeholders like ./path/to/your/php_project with the actual path to your PHP project and update database configurations as needed.